Is cold fusion the only avenue for fusion reactors?
To my understanding, cold fusion proposes a solution to usable fusion reactions by finding a way to fuse nuclei at room or near-room temperatures. However, I also understand that improving energy in vs energy out isn't the only issue for fusion. If we have more energy in than energy out (for example in H-bombs) it becomes difficult to contain. So whilst faith in cold fusion is in decline, does that mean usable and renewable fusion is also in decline, or are there other avenues of research beyond merely (and solely) lowering the temperature?

Cold fusion does not exist. Hot fusion is still a very active area of research.
